# F# and MSBuild Tool (silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, msbuild, f#, msbuild-task

We are trying to use Static Resources within a 100% F# Silverlight application.  Embeded within the XAML of the referencing control, everything works.  But once I pull them out I am a loss.  C# applications set the build action as: MSBuild:MarkupCompilePass1

Two questions

1) does VS 2010 support this tool yet in f# silverlight projects?
2) If not, then is there way to run it from a command line and then link the resource to the project staticaly?

Thx

T

Comment: I guess I don't entirely understand your question, but I am building F# programs from the command-line using MSBuild.exe. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the Build Action manually in VS in the F# project to match the C# Build Action?  I haven't tried it, but seems like it has a decent chance of working maybe.

More generally, if you make the .fsproj file look like the .csproj file, I expect it will probably work, though it may not be easy to do this from within VS (may need to edit project file manually perhaps).  I'd be interested to hear the results.

Comment: The last time I tried to make the project files look simiolar (was a RC version) it didn't work.  I Can have my engineers working on the full version work with this...

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for MSBuild:CompilePass1 or 2, May be we can expect that in the next version. As of now the only way is to embed it as a "Resource" and use Application.LoadComponent to dynamically build the baml. I did some blog posts WRT to WPF, this should work as-is for full fledged F# Silverlight apps too,

http://fadsworld.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/f-in-the-enterprise-i/

http://fadsworld.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/f-in-the-enterprise-ii-2/

If you need any help, do let me know.

-Fahad